# Transferring all things from iPad to iPad Air 2

Tags: ipad

I have just purchased an iPad Air 2. I wish to transfer games, letter, books stored in iBooks and photos. I also want to transfer my contacts for emails and Facetime. I apologise as I am not that computer literate.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it. First thing you need to make sure that your old iPad has the latest iOS, you can check in in Settings > General > About, check the version it should be 8.0 or above. After that you need to plug in your old iPad to your computer and in iTunes click on your iPad and in the Backups section select this computer and click back up now. After back up is done you can connect your new iPad Air 2 and select restore from back up. All your photos, contacts, emails etc should appear on your new iPad.

If you old iPad cannot run iOS 8 than I suggest you to enable iCloud on your old iPad, you can do it in Settings > iCloud and tick everything that you are willing to transfer to the new iPad Air 2. Set up your new iPad Air 2 as a new iPad and enable iCloud as well. All your data should appear on the new one. Please take some time as it will can take up to couple of hours depending on your internet speed. Photo synchronisation only works with wifi and no cellar signal.

Comment: If option 1 is working for you, don't forget to use a password when backing up your iPad. If you use a password for backup all used passwords etc. are stored, too!

Comment: I helped a coworker with a similar situation recently. She didn't have enough iCloud space and purchased extra for one month.

Answer (score 1):

[Transfer content from your previous iOS device to your new iPhone, iPad, or iPod touch](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201269)

That link contains instructions on how to use built-in migration features in iOS 11 or newer, or iCloud, or iTunes.